# Shopify (Node + React) custom app: verifyRequest() issue

Tags: shopify

I'm developing a custom embedded app with Node+React.

I followed the official tutorial but if I use the verifyRequest() middleware I always get the following error when I navigate through my app's pages:

> Expected a valid shop query parameter

I really can't understand what's wrong with the code.

Could anyone please help me?

Below is the server.js code

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const Koa = require('koa');
const next = require('next');
const { default: shopifyAuth } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-auth');
const { verifyRequest } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-auth');
const { default: Shopify, ApiVersion } = require('@shopify/shopify-api');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const RedisSessionStorage = require('./middleware/RedisSessionStorage')
const Cookies = require('cookies')

dotenv.config();

Shopify.Context.initialize({
    API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
    API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
    SCOPES: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SCOPES.split(","),
    HOST_NAME: process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
    API_VERSION: ApiVersion.April21,
    IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
    SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.CustomSessionStorage(
        RedisSessionStorage.storeCallback,
        RedisSessionStorage.loadCallback,
        RedisSessionStorage.deleteCallback,
    ),
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3001;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS = {[process.env.ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOP]: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SCOPES}

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = new Koa();
    const router = new Router();
    server.keys = [Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY];

    server.use(
        shopifyAuth({
            accessMode: 'offline',
            afterAuth(ctx) {
                const { shop, scope, accessToken } = ctx.state.shopify;
                global.accessToken = accessToken

                ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = scope;

                ctx.redirect(`/?shop=${shop}`);
            },
        }),
    );

    const handleRequest = async (ctx) => {
        await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
        ctx.respond = false;
        ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
    };

    router.get("/", async (ctx) => {
        const shop = ctx.query.shop;
        if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] === undefined) {
            ctx.redirect(`/auth?shop=${shop}`);
        } else {
            await handleRequest(ctx);
        }
    });

    router.get("(/_next/static/.*)", handleRequest);
    router.get("/_next/webpack-hmr", handleRequest);

    router.get("(.*)", verifyRequest({accessMode: 'offline'}), handleRequest);

    server.use(router.allowedMethods());
    server.use(router.routes());

    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the default SESSION_STORAGE?
It looks like it's directing to /auth

Comment: Tried but no luck. It seems that the app cannot read the shop parameter in the iframe URL.

The iframe URL I can see inspecting the code is something like:

https://123456.ngrok.io/?hmac=0077b9a7718f8f9af656726f7de374e4f504b341dc234ecd962409c82b46cb1f&host=bW9zY292YWRpc3RyaCN0bWEya2V0Lt15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4&locale=it&new_design_language=true&session=frr67120f3453b324813fa01df54000dfe77afb26e61292377c12d573ff1872&shop=myshop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1623398254